# Unable to bind view state to model

Tags: apache-flex

I am trying to bind my view currentState to a state variable that I have in my injected presentation model class.

If I do this:

```
<fx:Binding source="{model.state}" destination="{this.currentState}">
```

then I get an compiler error message `[project_name]: Initializer for 'destination': data binding expression not allowed here.`  The UIComponent property currentState has a public setter.

Why can't I make my view `currentState` property the target of binding?

Comment: Is this a compiler message or a runtime message?

Comment: The original message `unresolved variable or type 'currentState'` was coming from my IDE - IntelliJ.   The compiler error message is shown above.   I have edited the question to clarify.

Comment: You're trying to bind values in a binding tag. It expects only String values, so you should remove the `{}` curly braces. However I'm uncertain how `this` will be parsed.

Comment: Yes @RIAStar - that works.   I have also since found that putting the binding in the 'constructor' part of the MXML also works.   Please add your comment as an answer so that I can mark this as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer from @RIAStar works (see comments above). It is also possible to bind to currentState in the MXML constructor as indicated below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<s:Group
        xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
        xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
        currentState="{model.state}"
        >
```